# Calculate $\int_{∂B_R(0)} F \cdot ν dS_2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, gaussian-integral

So I have this exercise where I want to check if I have done everything right.

> Let $R > 0$ and $B_R(0) :=\{ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^3 : x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} < R\}$ be the open ball with radius R in $\mathbb{R}^3$ .
> Let $F : \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $F(x1, x2, x3) := (x_1x_{2}^{2} ,x_{1}^{2}x_2 + e^{x_3} , x_{3}^{3}/3 + x_{2}^{4})$ .

1. State the exterior normal vector $ν(x)$ for $x ∈ ∂B_R(0)$ without proof.
2. Calculate: $$\int_{∂B_R(0)} F\cdot ν dS_2.$$

Hint: It does not need to be shown that $B_R(0)$ is a $C^1$−bounded set.

So what I have done is:

i)$v(x)=(x_2^2,x_1^2,x_3^2)$

From there for 2. we have: $$\int_{∂B_R(0)} F\cdot ν dS_2\overset{\text{Using Gauss}}{=} \\ x_2^2+x_1^2+x_3^3d \lambda_3(x)\overset{\text{Using polar coordinates}}{=}\\ \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{pi}r^4sin(\phi)d\phi, d\alpha, dr= \\ \int_{0}^{R}r^4 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{pi}sin(\phi)d\phi, d\alpha, dr\\ =\int_{0}^{R}r^4 \int_{0}^{2\pi}[-cos(\phi)]_{0}^{pi}d\alpha, dr\\ =\int_{0}^{R}r^4 \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1d\alpha, dr=\\ 2\pi \int_{0}^{R}r^4 , dr=2\pi R/5$$

Is everything right or have I done any mistakes?

Comment: Your normal vector $\nu(x)$ is not correct and I think I see why. You took the gradient of the wrong object. The vector field (which you used in your calculation) and the set you integrate over (which you should be using) are independent from each other and have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I really dont get your point. I followed an example that we did in class. If you want I can send it to you via chat

Comment: You did not follow your example. You said $\nu(x) = (x_2^2,x_1^2,x_3^2)$, but these are the scalar components of the derivatives from Gauss' law. You were supposed to take the gradient of the equation of $\partial B_R(0)$, which is $$\nabla(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-R^2=0) \implies \nu = \frac{(2x_1,2x_2,2x_3)}{|(2x_1,2x_2,2x_3)|}$$ (since $\nu$ must be of unit length). The second part has the correct integrand, but some of the limits are not correct (can you guess where?).

Comment: I corrected the limits. But the Gauss's theorem says $\int_{V}\text{div} F d \lambda_n=\int_{∂A}F \cdot v dS_{n_1}$ with $\text{div} F=\sum_{j=1}^{n}∂_jF_j$ and in our case $\text{div} F=x_2^2+x_1^2+x_3^3$

Comment: Do you know what $\nu(x)$ is?

Comment: is the outer unit normal so the normal vector with length 1, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Do you see how the divergence is not the outer unit normal? Look at what you wrote down the outer unit normal as being.

Comment: Ahhh but you mean that I have wrongly written $\\ x_2^2,x_1^2,x_3^3d \lambda_3(x)$ instead of  $\\ x_2^2+x_1^2+x_3^3d \lambda_3(x)$? This was a typing error sorry

Comment: No I am not talking about that, I am talking about your answer for part 1

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I see my error